# editar archivos de un contenedor en docker

Tags: docker

Quisiera saber como poder editar archivos que están dentro de un contenedor en Docker, tengo este corriendo en localhost puerto 8443, quisiera hacer esto sin tener que entrar directamente al Docker y editar los archivos , es decir poder editarlos desde algún editor vscode etc. o alguna forma mas dinámica que ir archivo por archivo en el contenedor editando mis cambios y reiniciando el Docker

Comment: Podrías por favor ser más especifico, lo que indicas pareciera algo que se puede hacer con mucha facilidad si tu contener cuenta con un volumen que comparta con el sistema operativo base. Puedes compartir el script que usas para construir la imagen del contenedor?

Comment: en este link se encuentra la imagen de Docker que corre en localhost puerto 8443 por defecto entonces,esta tiene 4 contenedores 1 de ellos contiene archivos que necesito editar entonces cada vez que por ejemplo necesito editar algún archivo de ese contenedor lo que hago es entrar al contenedor usando el comando docker exec -ti container bash una vez dentro navego hasta el archivo que necesito lo modifico y guardo, en otros casos copio archivos locales al contenedor con el comando Docker cp pero quería saber si hay una forma mas rápida y flexible de hacer esto

Comment: https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet/archive/refs/tags/stable-5870.zip

Comment: La forma de hacerlo es usando volumenes https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una alternativa que puedes usar es copiarlo para tu entorno local, editarlos y luego subirlo al contenedor docker. Para copiarlo del contenedor docker al local y viceverza puedes usar el comando:

1. Copiar el fichero o toda la carpeta desde el contenedor docker a tu sistema local:

- `docker cp nombre_contenedor:/ruta/en/el/contenedor /ruta/en/tu/sistema/local`

2. Lo puedes editar en local con el editor que más guste y luego se sube los cambios al contenedor docker con el mismo comando:

- `docker cp /ruta/en/tu/sistema/local nombre_contenedor:/ruta/en/el/contenedor`